# Can you bless data/a computer program?

Tags: catholicism, blessings, thomism

This is a bit of a weird one. **Is it possible for a priest to bless data/a computer program?**

I ask because I'm considering writing a simple app for use by the faithful, and I like the idea of the app itself being blessed.

It becomes even weirder when you think about downloads; **are the copies blessed?**

I'd be especially interested if anyone can provide a Thomistic framework for this.

Either way, this seems a like a fun intellectual exercise, and I'm curious what people think. Thanks!

Comment: "this seems a like a fun intellectual exercise" then there's no point in doing it and its unfair on the whosoever is doing the blessing, because faith is serious and not for "marketing" and is otherwise not faith.

Comment: Program in Perl and you can "bless" any class you like--it's built in to the language.

Comment: On the other hand, use Linux/Unix as your operating system and your computer will be "possessed" with _daemons_ running  in background.

Comment: @Biblasia.  From several decades ago: [Godless devil-worshipping evil computers  — rec.humor.funny](https://www.netfunny.com/rhf/jokes/89q4/satan.773.html).

Comment: @M__ I was referring more to "this question is a fun intellectual exercise". I don't intend to use said blessing as a marketing matter. Faith is serious, I agree. That doesn't mean philosophy can't be a fun thing to do with your brain.

Comment: @Biblasia I had no idea that bless was a Perl keyword, neato! Thanks for the fun fact. I should learn Perl some time...

Comment: Warhammer Machine Spirits are leaking... No really, bless the hardware that it may not fail, bless the programmers that they may do quality work, and be inspired to find problems before they become big. But the program itself? That is like blessing a mathematical equation. I lack the imagination what you expect God to even do with a "blessed" program.

Comment: @kutschkem Only found out about the machine spirits recently, cracked me up. (EDIT, MISCLICK): So, part of what I want to make is a rosary. While it's not explicitly rosary beads, I'm curious if a rosary program that's been blessed could count as a blessed rosary.

Comment: @ConnieMnemonic I see. Now I wonder if there are any guidelines for a virtual rosary.

Answer (score 1):

**Is it possible for a priest to bless data/a computer program?**

In theory, it is quite possible.

Ask a priest to employ the [blessing “***ad Omnia***,”](http://www.rosarychurch.net/rituale/anything.html) when no other blessing is prescribed in the Roman Ritual...

> [P] Our help + is in the name of the Lord.
>
> [C] Who hath made heaven and earth.
>
> [P] The Lord be with you.
>
> [C] And with thy spirit.
>
> [P] Let us pray.
>
> O God, by whose word all things are made holy, pour down Thy blessing + on this [these] which Thou hast created. Grant that whoever, giving thanks to Thee, and making use of it [them] according to Thy will and law, may, by calling upon Thy holy name, receive through Thine aid, health of body and protection of soul. Through Christ our Lord.
>
> [C] Amen.

Or in Latin if you prefer:

> BENEDICTIO AD OMNIA [**Benedictio Ad Omnia**](https://christusregnat.com/2016/09/04/benedictio-ad-omnia/)
>
> HÆC BENEDICTIONIS FORMULA ADHIBERI POTEST A QUOVIS SACERDOTE PRO OMNIBUS REBUS, QUARUM SPECIALIS BENEDICTIO IN RITUALI ROMANO NON HABETUR.
>
> V. Adiutórium nostrum + in nómine Dómini.
>
> R. Qui fecit cælum et terram.
>
> V. Dominus vobíscum.
>
> R. Et cum spíritu tuo.
>
> **Oratio**
>
> Orémus.
>
> Deus, cuius verbo sanctificántur ómnia, béne+dictiónem tuam effúnde super creatúram istam (creatúras istas): et præsta, ut quisquis ea (eis) secúndum legem et voluntátem tuam cum gratiárum actióne usus fúerit, per invocatiónem sanctíssimi nominis tui, córporis sanitátem et ánimæ tutélam, te auctóre, percípiat. Per Dóminum nóstrum Iesum Christum Fílium tuum: Qui tecum vivit et regnat in unitáte Spíritus Sancti Deus per ómnia sǽcula sæculórum.
>
> R. Amen.

Comment: So, in the link you've provided, it ends with "The blessed objects are sprinkled with holy water." EDIT (MISCLICK): How can this apply to data? You could sprinkle the computer itself, but does that affect the data itself?

Comment: @ConnieMnemonic Maybe you're asking if immaterial beings ("intellectual property", ideas, patents, etc.) can be blessed?

Comment: That's an interesting point @Geremia. I guess that's quite applicable! It's interesting to try and distinguish between "information" and "medium" - the program itself is, essentially, information, but it's stored; there's a physical medium in terms of electrons and magnetic alignments and transistor sets.

Answer (score 0):

These blessings might be of interest, which can be found in Weller's 1950 Latin-English [*Roman Ritual*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=7240) vol. 3, pp.

- 402-406: Blessing of an Electric Generator (*Benedictio machinæ ad excitandam lucem electricam*)

  > From the the clergy nearest church or from some other place previously appointed, the clergy proceed in solemn some manner to the power station, as they chant or recite: […]
- 410-418: Blessing of a Telegraph (*Benedictio telegraphi*)

  > From the nearest church or from another place previously appointed, the clergy proceed in solemn manner to the telegraph station, chanting or reciting:

Both of these blessings are "reserved to the [Ordinary](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=35302) [local bishop] or to one delegated by him", presumably because both these things cover large geographical areas.

It seems that blessing a computer program that is distributed globally would need to be blessed by someone with global jurisdiction (the pope).

It is interesting these are approved blessings, as "General Rules Concerning Blessings", [*ibid.*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=7240) p. 3 says

> 4. Objects which have received the constitutive blessing should be treated reverently, and should never be put to profane or im­proper use, even though they may be in private possession.

Unless these generators and telegraphs to be blessed are only connecting churches or used only by priests, it's hard to see how they would not (at least partially) "be put to profane" use.